# Need to identify 4-way latching connector to seat safety switch on Cub Cadet ZTR mower (images included)

Tags: identification, connector

### Connector Identification

I need to create an extension cable for a cable with the connector shown in the attached images. I'm having trouble identifying the connector. Can anyone tell me **the name of this type of connector?** And if possible, a potential purchase source for male & female versions (or even a pre-made extension cable with this connector).

### Details

It's a cable that connects to the seat's safety switch on a Cub Cadet ZTR mower. I'm adding an after market seat suspension and need to extend the cable. But I need to plug the extension into the seat's switch before I attach the suspension kit (as there's no way to get in there to plug it in once the suspension kit is attached to the seat). And then be able to plug the other end of the extension cable into the "built-in" cable after reinstalling the seat on the tractor. So I really need to be able to have a cable dangling off the seat (i.e. my extension cable) with the suspension kit attached. I want to use the same connector so I do not have to splice into the the mower's cable (in order to create an extension with an alternate connector) due to the whole void your warranty thing.

### Images

[image: Image 1 Top at angle with dimension]
[image: Image 2 Top]
[image: Image 3 Front at angle]
[image: Image 4 Front]
[image: Image 5 Back showing latch]

*EDIT: Some additional images against a light background*
[image: Image 6 Top with light background]
[image: Image 7 Front against light background]
[image: Image 8 Front at angle against light background]

Unfortunately, the parts diagram is not if much help. And the connector is part of the main wiring harness, which costs $410. (It's an electric mower, and thus the main wiring harness goes to all four motors, drive levers, control panel, lights, and safety switches.) So not viable to buy to just get the one connector.

[image: wiring harness]

Comment: Your best bet is to look up the parts catalog for the mower, and see if there are any wiring sub-harnesses that you could scavenge the connectors from. It’s likely to be a custom molded connector with some mainstream pins/sockets.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it is part of the main wiring harness, which is $410. (And is on back order on top of that.) I added an image of it to my post. It's an electric mower (ZT1 42E) so the wiring harness is much more extensive than on a typical ZTR mower, and thus likely why it so expensive. If it is a custom molded part (didn't realize manufactures did that), then I guess I'll have to go the route of splicing into it.

Comment: Worst case scenario, find out if the pins are standard, buy them and 3D print the housing.

Comment: Please post pictures of its mate: the connector that this plug plugs into.

Comment: Can you snip the wires and subsitute your own favourite connector pair?